# Android Facebook Graph API to update status

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've tried to update the status using the Facebook graph API with Android http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/
So, my question is if you can give me some example code to update status using this API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, This may not be a perfect code, but it works for now. You'll have to modify how and when it is called to get a better user Experience:

```
//Implementing SSO
    facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR","FB ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.e("ERROR","AUTH ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("CANCELLED","AUTH CANCELLED");
        }
    });
```

This is the function that updates:

```
//updating Status
public void updateStatus(String accessToken){
    try {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", "test update");
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my complete solution using the Graph API

If all you intend to do is update the users status you only need to get the "publish_stream" permission.
From developers.facebook.com...
"publish_stream": Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, **without requiring offline_access**. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user-initiated sharing model.

This is important because it means you do not need to re-authorize every time you attempt to update the status.  The trick is to save the key/token and send it with any update request.

One note: I changed "Facebook.DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE" from private to public in the Facebook.java class.

My code has two buttons one that checks for a saved token and one that just sends a blank token so I could test what happens if the token fails for some reason.  If it does fail, and the API returns a string with "OAuthException" this code makes a new attempt to authorize, then tries to update the status again.

## FBTest.java

```
package com.test.FBTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;

public class FBTest extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("199064386804603");
EditText et1;
TextView tv1;
Button button1;
Button button2;

private int mAuthAttempts = 0;
private String mFacebookToken;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b1Click();
        }

    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b2Click();
        }

    });
}

private void saveFBToken(String token, long tokenExpires){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putString("FacebookToken", token).commit();
}

private void fbAuthAndPost(final String message){

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize Complete: ");
            saveFBToken(facebook.getAccessToken(), facebook.getAccessExpires());
            updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN), message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize Error: "+error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize DialogError: "+e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook authorization canceled");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
    case Facebook.DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE:
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void b1Click(){

    mAuthAttempts = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mFacebookToken = prefs.getString("FacebookToken", "");

    if(mFacebookToken.equals("")){
        fbAuthAndPost(et1.getText().toString());
    }else{
        updateStatus(mFacebookToken,et1.getText().toString());
    }

}

private void b2Click(){
    mAuthAttempts = 0;
    updateStatus("",et1.getText().toString());
}

public void updateStatus(String accessToken, String message){  

    try {         
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", message);         
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);         
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");         
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
        showToast("Update process complete. Respose:"+response);
        if(response.indexOf("OAuthException") > -1){
            if(mAuthAttempts==0){
                mAuthAttempts++;
                fbAuthAndPost(message);
            }else{
                showToast("OAuthException:");
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {         
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("MalformedURLException:"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {         
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("IOException:"+e.getMessage());
    }

    String s = facebook.getAccessToken()+"\n";
    s += String.valueOf(facebook.getAccessExpires())+"\n";
    s += "Now:"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+"\n";
    tv1.setText(s);

} 

private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

## main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/EditText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:text="Test: With Auth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:text="Test: Without Auth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/TextView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect. Hovewer the app pops up a dialog very frequently saying "you already authorized this app [OK]". Any way to get rid of it?

Comment: @aloneguid - You will get that dialog every time you attempt to authorize your app.  The point is to authorize once and save the token in your app data.  Then you can use that token with the updateStatus function without the need to re-authorize.

Comment: EddieB much obliged, everything just works, didn't have to dig their monstrous examples to understand how to do the simplest update.