# Android Facebook SDK authorize methods shows dialog every time

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, single-sign-on

I'm writing an Android application that should upload photos to Facebook.

Everything works just fine except one thing. When I called the Facebook.authorize() method for the first time the Facebook dialog was shown with requested permissions and 'Allow'/'Don't Allow' buttons. That was OK. But when I run my app for the secong time I've got the same dialog, but with message that my application allowed already and suggestion to press OK button.

Is there a way to avoid this second dialog? Should I skip the authorize method in some conditions?

I tried to call the Facebook.isSessionValid() method before authorize method, but this did not help.

Here is my simplified code:

```
    mFacebook = new Facebook(APPLICATION_ID);
    mFacebookAsync = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    if (mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        uploadPictureFile();
    }
    else {
        mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"publish_stream"}, new Facebook.DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoFeederFacebookSendActivity.this, "Facebook error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finishWithResultCode(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(PhotoFeederFacebookSendActivity.this, "Facebook dialog error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finishWithResultCode(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                uploadPictureFile();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {Toast.makeText(PhotoFeederFacebookSendActivity.this, "Facebook authorization cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finishWithResultCode(RESULT_CANCELED);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is my onActivityResult method:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As of now, I am also facing this issue. Unlike twitter, we have to open the authorise dialog every time we have to perform any function.

Comment: Ok, I have solved this myself. I'm saving session information in the shared preferences as this done in the Facebook examples. And when my app is executed for the second time I'm just restoring session info from the preferences and pass it to Facebook object.

Comment: Alexey, can you elaborate?  What if the user logs out and then back in?  As far as I understand, that'll require calling authorize(), and will thus show the authorize dialog saying that the app has already been authorized.  I can save off the access token, but if the user logs out, it becomes invalid, thus requiring them to log back in, and we're back at the same problem.

Comment: It looks to me like they've added code to make sure the authorization flows through the official Facebook app on the phone; it looks at intent information to make sure it's not hacked, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `mFacebook.setAccessToken("your token")` before `mFacebook.isSessionValid()`
and you need to save the token to preference yourself

Comment: This solves the problem in short term. The session is only a hour or so long, so user might still face that "Already authorized" dialog every day. I assume "offline_access" permission and non-expiring sessions would get around this. But since we don't in fact need *offline* access, a better solution would first try to establish session in background. Then, if user is not logged in or rights are not granted, would get "connect" buttton or dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you only intend to update status see my post here...
[Android Facebook Graph API to update status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641680/android-facebook-graph-api-to-update-status/6002634#6002634)