# Android post to facebook wall, stream.publish broken since few days

Tags: android, facebook

I have a lot of apps published using the FB android sdk

github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

All my applications that use FB stopped working since few days.
This is necessarily a change or a bug from FB side, because nothing has changed in my applications, It worked for months.

The dialog that opens to post a message ("stream.publish") seems not use the param "message", the form opens but the text box is empty!

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "test message");                                          
mFacebook.dialog(Example.this, "stream.publish", parameters,new SampleDialogListener());
```

Using debug I saw the URL with the "message" param:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/stream.publish?message=test+message&app_id=....

The text input in the webview is emtpy!

Somebody have an idea or a workaround to fix this issue?

Comment: I also notified the bug here: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem for the last few days. Looks like Facebook is deprecating the Stream API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/, not sure if this has anything to do with that.

Anyway, switching to using the Graph API's 'feed' method worked for me.

Comment: Ok I solved my problem using the graph API, here an example
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641680/android-facebook-graph-api-to-update-status

Facebook is now ignoring the message parameter
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

[facebook update](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/).

Answer (score 2):

Try "feed" instead of "stream.publish"

Comment: This worked for me. An example on how to use the "feed": http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/