# Facebook SDK force close

Tags: android, facebook

My app wants to share music to Facebook by using Facebook's SDK for share function. Earlier it was working but now it force closes at parseUrl method. Can anyone help me ? thank you.

sorry and thank you for your help and this is my code

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("123456789123456");
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();   

    parameters.putString("caption" , " ");
    parameters.putString("description" , "http://www.music.com");
    parameters.putString("name" , "(Sweet)");
    facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, 
    new DialogListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) 
        {
            /*try 
            {
                facebook.logout(getApplicationContext());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}
```

here is a logcat

```
08-24 13:01:06.734: ERROR/LoadListener.java(4987): @@@@@@@@@@ mCacheType detachRequestHandle() --> mCacheType0
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at com.facebook.android.Util.decodeUrl(Util.java:97)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at com.facebook.android.Util.parseUrl(Util.java:115)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at com.facebook.android.FbDialog$FbWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(FbDialog.java:125)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:232)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:359)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-24 13:01:07.097: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4987):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 13:01:07.128: ERROR/(158): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is causing you the problem? We can't help you without more details.

Comment: Post the LogCat output and some of your code which causes the crash.

Comment: copy paste the logcat here. It also helps if you could show the part of your code that may cause problem.

Comment: It is possible that Facebook have removed the application.

Comment: now I post my code and my logcat everyone please help me thank you

Comment: Just wondering, does this repro if you put something nonempty in the caption?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is going to ditch the `stream.publish` functionality (see [this notice](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/)). Recently, other people on SO have complained about [problems with stream.publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942403/android-post-to-facebook-wall-stream-publish-broken-since-few-days) as well. I guess the new facebook API is now a bit buggy when it comes to publishing via streams. You'd better switch to posting via the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue lately. For some reason, one of the parameters is going in as a `-` which can not be broken into two strings.
Fixed it by injecting a check on `com\facebook\android\Util.java`

Modified `decodeUrl` method given below.

```
public static Bundle decodeUrl(String s) 
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    if (s != null) 
    {
        String array[] = s.split("&");
        for (String parameter : array) 
        {
            String v[] = parameter.split("=");

            if(v.length >= 2)
            {
                params.putString(URLDecoder.decode(v[0]), 
                                    URLDecoder.decode(v[1]));
            }
        }
    }
    return params;
}
```