# Allow users to automatically forward statuses to facebook from Android app permently

Tags: android, facebook, post, updates, facebook-android-sdk

So I have a social app built for android that allows users to post status updates (on my service) and i want to give my users the ability to have their statuses forwarded to facebook automatically similar to how Twitter allows you to automatically post your tweets to fb , but after looking at the documentation and googling all i can really find a example of is a means to post a single spam-ish type status that causes a webview dialog to pop up every time.

How do the 3rd party fb client apps pull this off? (the ones where at the bottom of the post it says "posted from tweetdeck" ect.

Comment: What exactly you want? Can you give an example?

Comment: This might be what you want to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641680/android-facebook-graph-api-to-update-status

Comment: Note that the above stackoverflow link is very old and uses now deprecated classes and methods in the SDK. You should use the Facebook SDK for Android: https://developers.facebook.com/android/, and follow the guide here to publish to feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/

Comment: I want to have a option in my settings " Forward my posts on Buhz to Facebook" and if a user selects this option I want the statuses my users post on my service to be posted on facebook with no additional pop up dialogs or anything like that. Identical to the feature twitter has to forward tweets to facebook as statuses automatically

Comment: @MingLi , I am not stupid. I am well aware of the Facebook Android SDK and have already implemented a Facebook Oauth system , the problem is that it seems they have hidden or made it hard to have it setup so that statuses are posted without one of their big annoying pop up webviews dialogs every time a user posts a status

Comment: @ChuckKelly, I'm sorry if my comment could be interpreted otherwise, but nowhere did I imply anything about your intelligence. AFAIK, the third party FB clients all ask for publish_actions permissions, and issues a graph API request (as outlined in the feed documentation I linked). If you have the publish_actions permission, you do not need to have any popup webviews as you can post directly on the user's behalf.